# My PC have no IP address and routing table

Tags: lan, centos-5

I am a newbie in sysadmin.

Am having a problem with my comp PC.
The new DEL XPS 8700 with windows, has been replaced with CentOS 5.10 (OS used currently by my comp).

After uninstalled the windows, the network of the PC cant be accessed at all.
LAN specifically.

Below are the details:

## ifconfig -a

eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr F8:B1:56:B3:65:**
          BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1 
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0 
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0 
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 b)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 b) 
          Interrupt:58 Base address:0x2000

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback
          inet addr:127.0.0.*  Mask:255.0.0.0 
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host 
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1 
          RX packets:1223 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0 
          TX packets:1223 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0 
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:2318264 (2.2 MiB)  TX bytes:2318264 (2.2 MiB)

sit0      Link encap:IPv6-in-IPv4
          NOARP  MTU:1480  Metric:1 
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0 
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0 
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 b)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 b)

## netstat -rn

Kernel IP routing table 
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags   MSS Window  irtt Iface

## service network restart

Shutting down loopback interface:                          [  OK  ] 
Bringing up loopback interface:                            [  OK  ] 
Bringing up interface eth1:  r8169 device eth1 does not seem to be present, delaying initialization. 
                                                           [FAILED]

## lspci -nn

00:00.0 Host bridge [0600]: Intel Corporation 4th Gen Core Processor DRAM Controller [8086:0c00] (rev 06) 
00:01.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor PCI Express x16 Controller [8086:0c01] (rev 06) 
00:14.0 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family USB xHCI [8086:8c31] (rev 05) 
00:16.0 Communication controller [0780]: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 [8086:8c3a] (rev 04) 
00:1a.0 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family USB EHCI #2 [8086:8c2d] (rev 05) 
00:1b.0 Audio device [0403]: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset High Definition Audio Controller [8086:8c20] (rev 05) 
00:1c.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #1 [8086:8c10] (rev d5) 
00:1c.2 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #3 [8086:8c14] (rev d5) 
00:1c.7 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #8 [8086:8c1e] (rev d5) 
00:1d.0 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family USB EHCI #1 [8086:8c26] (rev 05) 
00:1f.0 ISA bridge [0601]: Intel Corporation Z87 Express LPC Controller [8086:8c44] (rev 05) 
00:1f.2 SATA controller [0106]: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family 6-port SATA Controller 1 [AHCI mode] [8086:8c02] (rev 05) 
00:1f.3 SMBus [0c05]: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller [8086:8c22] (rev 05) 
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: NVIDIA Corporation GK208 [GeForce GT 635] [10de:1280] (rev a1) 
01:00.1 Audio device [0403]: NVIDIA Corporation Device [10de:0e0f] (rev a1) 
03:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 0c) 
04:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros AR9485 Wireless Network Adapter [168c:0032] (rev 01)

## dhclient

Internet Systems Consortium DHCP Client V3.0.5-RedHat 
Copyright 2004-2006 Internet Systems Consortium. 
All rights reserved. 
For info, please visit http://www.isc.org/sw/dhcp/

/sbin/dhclient-script: configuration for eth0 not found. Continuing with defaults. 
/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/network-functions: line 78: eth0: No such file or directory 
Listening on LPF/eth0/f8:b1:56:b3:65:** 
Sending on   LPF/eth0/f8:b1:56:b3:65:** 
Sending on   Socket/fallback 
DHCPDISCOVER on eth0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 6 (xid=0x66a28d5b) 
DHCPDISCOVER on eth0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 14 (xid=0x66a28d5b) 
DHCPDISCOVER on eth0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 8 (xid=0x66a28d5b) 
DHCPDISCOVER on eth0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 16 (xid=0x66a28d5b) 
DHCPDISCOVER on eth0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 13 (xid=0x66a28d5b) 
DHCPDISCOVER on eth0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 4 (xid=0x66a28d5b) 
No DHCPOFFERS received. 
No working leases in persistent database - sleeping. 
/sbin/dhclient-script: configuration for eth0 not found. Continuing with defaults. 
/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/network-functions: line 78: eth0: No such file or directory

[root@localhost network-scripts]# ls

ifcfg-eth0~  ifdown-ipsec   ifup          ifup-plip      init.ipv6-global 
ifcfg-eth1   ifdown-ipv6    ifup-aliases  ifup-plusb     net.hotplug 
ifcfg-eth1~  ifdown-isdn    ifup-bnep     ifup-post      network-functions 
ifcfg-lo     ifdown-post    ifup-eth      ifup-ppp       network-functions-ipv6 
ifcfg-lo~    ifdown-ppp     ifup-ippp     ifup-routes    route-eth1 
ifdown       ifdown-routes  ifup-ipsec    ifup-sit 
ifdown-bnep  ifdown-sit     ifup-ipv6     ifup-sl 
ifdown-eth   ifdown-sl      ifup-ipx      ifup-tunnel 
ifdown-ippp  ifdown-tunnel  ifup-isdn     ifup-wireless

## ping localhost

PING localhost.localdomain (127.0.0.*) 56(84) bytes of data. 
64 bytes from localhost.localdomain (127.0.0.*): icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.067 ms 
64 bytes from localhost.localdomain (127.0.0.*): icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.035 ms 
64 bytes from localhost.localdomain (127.0.0.*): icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=0.032 ms 
64 bytes from localhost.localdomain (127.0.0.*): icmp_seq=4 ttl=64 time=0.032 ms 
64 bytes from localhost.localdomain (127.0.0.*): icmp_seq=5 ttl=64 time=0.030 ms 
64 bytes from localhost.localdomain (127.0.0.*): icmp_seq=6 ttl=64 time=0.031 ms 
64 bytes from localhost.localdomain (127.0.0.*): icmp_seq=7 ttl=64 time=0.030 ms

[1]+  Stopped                 ping localhost

## ping 192.168.1.*

connect: Network is unreachable

I have no idea on what else to do.

I have done:

-#HWADDR

-add the eth0 device 
(default setting are device of eth1 : because some artcle mentioned on error of geting eth1 on initial start)

Can anyone help me please?

Thank you.

Comment: When you execute a command and paste its output, you should use code blocks to be more readable. Indent all what you copy/paste with 4 spaces.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be the key.
try reading dmesg or syslog after doing the networking restart and see whats wrong.

```
Bringing up interface eth1: r8169 device eth1 does not seem to be present, delaying initialization. [FAILED]
```

Seems like your interface is on eth1 (not eth0) and it's not loading at all

Answer (score 0):

Since the network service returns you this message :

```
Bringing up interface eth1: r8169 device eth1 does not seem to be present, delaying initialization. [FAILED]
```

It seems you configured your network on the `eth1` interface. However, `ifconfig -a` doesn't show any `eth1` interface but an `eth0`. You computer should have only one Ethernet network card, so you should have only one `eth` interface called `eth0`.

In this case, you should try moving `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth1` to `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0`, and then editing it to replace `DEVICE=eth1` by `DEVICE=eth0`. While editing it, also check you have `BOOTPROTO=dhcp` and `ONBOOT=yes`, which enable the interface at boot and use DHCP to configure it.

Comment: i already did that. i solved it by upgrading to CentOS 6. thank you @piernov! it turns out that this desktop is not compatible with Cent0S 5, but works wonder with Cent0S 6.